# Can a "Help Settings" Visualforce page set on a custom object be surfaced in Lightning Experience?

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, lightning-experience, help

Our custom objects have their "Help Settings" attributes set up to reference Visualforce pages that in turn display HTML content from a static resource included in our managed package. This material is presented when the "Help for this Page" link is clicked. We have successfully used this approach for many years in Classic.

Is there a way to expose this help in Lightning Experience?

Comment: Curious here - what does the "?" menu show in LEX, does it not by default pull up that link? EDITED: And I now see from the [**documentation**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_find_help.htm&type=5) -- You can’t customize the items in the help menu. If you’ve created custom help links, those links still work from the “Help for this Page” links in the framed Salesforce Classic pages. However, your custom help links don’t appear in the new Help menu.

Comment: @JayantDas Thanks. The case I'm interested in is when using normal layouts; in Classic you get the link but in Lightning you don't.

Comment: And looks like you may be out of luck here, until you build anything custom, as the documentation mentions that custom help links don't appear in the new Help menu.